# Finding maximum value of column, and returning value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   Allotment  NDII Percent  NDII Value  NDVI Percent  NDVI Value
0    Arnston        0.0550   -0.199448           NaN         NaN
1    Arnston        0.0000   -0.198036           NaN         NaN
2    Arnston        0.0000   -0.196623           NaN         NaN
3    Arnston        0.0000   -0.195211           NaN         NaN
4    Arnston        0.0000   -0.193799           NaN         NaN
5    Arnston        0.0275   -0.192386           NaN         NaN
6    Arnston        0.0550   -0.190974           NaN         NaN
7    Arnston        0.0000   -0.189561           NaN         NaN
8    Arnston        0.0275   -0.188149           NaN         NaN
9    Arnston        0.1926   -0.186737           NaN         NaN
10      Anex        0.0275   -0.185324           NaN         NaN
11      Anex        0.0275   -0.183912           NaN         NaN
12      Anex        0.1376   -0.182499           NaN         NaN
13      Anex        0.0000   -0.181087           NaN         NaN
14      Anex        0.1100   -0.179675           NaN         NaN
15      Anex        0.0550   -0.178262           NaN         NaN
16      Anex        0.0000   -0.176850           NaN         NaN
17      Anex        0.0275   -0.175437           NaN         NaN
18      Anex        0.1100   -0.174025           NaN         NaN
0    Arnston           NaN         NaN        5.0338    0.000000
1    Arnston           NaN         NaN        1.0000    0.002235
2    Arnston           NaN         NaN        0.0200    0.004469
3    Arnston           NaN         NaN        0.1000    0.006704
4    Arnston           NaN         NaN        2.0000    0.008939
5    Arnston           NaN         NaN        1.0000    0.011173
6    Arnston           NaN         NaN        2.0000    0.013408
7    Arnston           NaN         NaN        0.0000    0.015643
8    Arnston           NaN         NaN        0.0000    0.017877
9    Arnston           NaN         NaN        0.0000    0.020112
10   Arnston           NaN         NaN        0.0000    0.022346
11      Anex           NaN         NaN        1.0000    0.024581
12      Anex           NaN         NaN        3.0000    0.026816
13      Anex           NaN         NaN        5.0000    0.029050
14      Anex           NaN         NaN        0.0000    0.031285
15      Anex           NaN         NaN        0.0000    0.033520
16      Anex           NaN         NaN        0.0000    0.035754
17      Anex           NaN         NaN        0.0000    0.037989
18      Anex           NaN         NaN        0.0000    0.040224
19      Anex           NaN         NaN        0.0000    0.042458
20      Anex           NaN         NaN        0.0000    0.044693
21      Anex           NaN         NaN        0.0000    0.046928
22      Anex           NaN         NaN        0.0000    0.049162
23      Anex           NaN         NaN        0.0000    0.051397
24      Anex           NaN         NaN        0.0000    0.053631
25      Anex           NaN         NaN        0.0000    0.055866
26      Anex           NaN         NaN        0.0000    0.058101
```

and I want to find the Maximum `NDII Value` and its associated `NDII Percent` for each `Allotment` and the maximum `NDVI Value` and its associated `NDVI Percent` for each `Allotment`.  So I know I will need to use a groupby on the `Allotment` first, but that is where I am getting stuck.

My desired output is:

```
Allotment    NDII Percent NDII Value   NDVI Percent   NDVI Value
Arnston      0.1926       -0.186737    0.0000         0.022346
Anex         0.1100       -0.174025    0.0000         0.058101
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there's a more straight and elegant way to do this but, let `df` be your original dataframe:

```
df1 = df.iloc[df.groupby(['Allotment'])['NDII Value'].apply(lambda x: x.idxmax())]
df2 = df.iloc[df.groupby(['Allotment'])['NDVI Value'].apply(lambda x: x.idxmax())]
```

Then I'm selecting only the columns I need:

```
d1 = df1[['Allotment','NDII Value','NDII Percent']]
d2 = df2[['Allotment','NDVI Value','NDVI Percent']]
```

and merge:

```
d = d1.merge(d2,how='outer')
```

This returns:

```
  Allotment  NDII Value  NDII Percent  NDVI Value  NDVI Percent
0      Anex   -0.174025        0.1100    0.058101             0
1   Arnston   -0.186737        0.1926    0.022346             0
```

Hope that helps.